# Combining conditional expressions with "AND" and "OR" predicates using the JPA criteria API

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, criteria

I need to adapt the following code example.

I've got a MySQL query, which looks like this (2015-05-04 and 2015-05-06 are dynamic and symbolize a time range)

```sql
SELECT * FROM cars c WHERE c.id NOT IN ( SELECT fkCarId FROM bookings WHERE 
    (fromDate <= '2015-05-04' AND toDate >= '2015-05-04') OR
    (fromDate <= '2015-05-06' AND toDate >= '2015-05-06') OR
    (fromDate >= '2015-05-04' AND toDate <= '2015-05-06'))
```

I've got a `bookings` table, and a `cars` table. I'd like to find out which car is available in a time range. The SQL query works like a charm.

I'd like to "convert" this one into a `CriteriaBuilder` output. I've read documentation during the last 3 hours with this output (which, obviously, does not work). And I even skipped the where parts in the sub queries.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Cars> query = cb.createQuery(Cars.class);
Root<Cars> poRoot = query.from(Cars.class);
query.select(poRoot);

Subquery<Bookings> subquery = query.subquery(Bookings.class);
Root<Bookings> subRoot = subquery.from(Bookings.class);
subquery.select(subRoot);
Predicate p = cb.equal(subRoot.get(Bookings_.fkCarId),poRoot);
subquery.where(p);

TypedQuery<Cars> typedQuery = getEntityManager().createQuery(query);

List<Cars> result = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

Another issue: the `fkCarId` is not defined as a foreign key, it's just an integer. Any way to get it fixed that way?

Comment: One thing to note is that your date conditions sum up to `fromDate >= '2015-05-04' AND toDate <= '2015-05-06'`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be editing it. It should be a dynamic time range. If a car is booked from 2015-05-05 to 2015-05-07, one should not be able to book it, when either the begin date, or the end date, or both conflict with an existing booking.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I have created the following two tables in MySQL database with only the necessary fields.

```sql
mysql> desc cars;
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| car_id       | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| manufacturer | varchar(100)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> desc bookings;
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| booking_id | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| fk_car_id  | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| from_date  | date                | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| to_date    | date                | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

`booking_id` in the `bookings` table is a primary key and `fk_car_id` is a foreign key that references the primary key (`car_id`) of the `cars` table.

---

The corresponding JPA criteria query using an `IN()` sub-query goes like the following.

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Cars> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Cars.class);
Metamodel metamodel = entityManager.getMetamodel();
Root<Cars> root = criteriaQuery.from(metamodel.entity(Cars.class));

Subquery<Long> subquery = criteriaQuery.subquery(Long.class);
Root<Bookings> subRoot = subquery.from(metamodel.entity(Bookings.class));
subquery.select(subRoot.get(Bookings_.fkCarId).get(Cars_.carId));

List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

ParameterExpression<Date> fromDate1 = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Date.class);
Predicate exp1 = criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(subRoot.get(Bookings_.fromDate), fromDate1);
ParameterExpression<Date> toDate1 = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Date.class);
Predicate exp2 = criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(subRoot.get(Bookings_.toDate), toDate1);
Predicate and1 = criteriaBuilder.and(exp1, exp2);

ParameterExpression<Date> fromDate2 = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Date.class);
Predicate exp3 = criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(subRoot.get(Bookings_.fromDate), fromDate2);
ParameterExpression<Date> toDate2 = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Date.class);
Predicate exp4 = criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(subRoot.get(Bookings_.toDate), toDate2);
Predicate and2 = criteriaBuilder.and(exp3, exp4);

ParameterExpression<Date> fromDate3 = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Date.class);
Predicate exp5 = criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(subRoot.get(Bookings_.fromDate), fromDate3);
ParameterExpression<Date> toDate3 = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Date.class);
Predicate exp6 = criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(subRoot.get(Bookings_.toDate), toDate3);
Predicate and3 = criteriaBuilder.and(exp5, exp6);

Predicate or = criteriaBuilder.or(and1, and2, and3);
predicates.add(or);
subquery.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));

criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.in(root.get(Cars_.carId)).value(subquery).not());

List<Cars> list = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery)
        .setParameter(fromDate1, new Date("2015/05/04"))
        .setParameter(toDate1, new Date("2015/05/04"))
        .setParameter(fromDate2, new Date("2015/05/06"))
        .setParameter(toDate2, new Date("2015/05/06"))
        .setParameter(fromDate3, new Date("2015/05/04"))
        .setParameter(toDate3, new Date("2015/05/06"))
        .getResultList();
```

It produces the following SQL query of your interest (tested on Hibernate 4.3.6 final but there should not be any discrepancy on average ORM frameworks in this context).

```sql
SELECT
    cars0_.car_id AS car_id1_7_,
    cars0_.manufacturer AS manufact2_7_ 
FROM
    project.cars cars0_ 
WHERE
    cars0_.car_id NOT IN  (
        SELECT
            bookings1_.fk_car_id 
        FROM
            project.bookings bookings1_ 
        WHERE
            bookings1_.from_date<=? 
            AND bookings1_.to_date>=? 
            OR bookings1_.from_date<=? 
            AND bookings1_.to_date>=? 
            OR bookings1_.from_date>=? 
            AND bookings1_.to_date<=?
    )
```

<sub>Brackets around the conditional expressions in the `WHERE` clause of the above query are technically utterly superfluous which are only needed for better a readability which Hibernate disregards - Hibernate does not have to take them into consideration.</sub>

---

I personally however, prefer to use the `EXISTS` operator. Accordingly, the query can be reconstructed as follows.

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Cars> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Cars.class);
Metamodel metamodel = entityManager.getMetamodel();
Root<Cars> root = criteriaQuery.from(metamodel.entity(Cars.class));

Subquery<Long> subquery = criteriaQuery.subquery(Long.class);
Root<Bookings> subRoot = subquery.from(metamodel.entity(Bookings.class));
subquery.select(criteriaBuilder.literal(1L));

List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

ParameterExpression<Date> fromDate1 = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Date.class);
Predicate exp1 = criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(subRoot.get(Bookings_.fromDate), fromDate1);
ParameterExpression<Date> toDate1 = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Date.class);
Predicate exp2 = criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(subRoot.get(Bookings_.toDate), toDate1);
Predicate and1 = criteriaBuilder.and(exp1, exp2);

ParameterExpression<Date> fromDate2 = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Date.class);
Predicate exp3 = criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(subRoot.get(Bookings_.fromDate), fromDate2);
ParameterExpression<Date> toDate2 = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Date.class);
Predicate exp4 = criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(subRoot.get(Bookings_.toDate), toDate2);
Predicate and2 = criteriaBuilder.and(exp3, exp4);

ParameterExpression<Date> fromDate3 = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Date.class);
Predicate exp5 = criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(subRoot.get(Bookings_.fromDate), fromDate3);
ParameterExpression<Date> toDate3 = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Date.class);
Predicate exp6 = criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(subRoot.get(Bookings_.toDate), toDate3);
Predicate and3 = criteriaBuilder.and(exp5, exp6);

Predicate equal = criteriaBuilder.equal(root, subRoot.get(Bookings_.fkCarId));
Predicate or = criteriaBuilder.or(and1, and2, and3);
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(or, equal));
subquery.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));

criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.exists(subquery).not());

List<Cars> list = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery)
        .setParameter(fromDate1, new Date("2015/05/04"))
        .setParameter(toDate1, new Date("2015/05/04"))
        .setParameter(fromDate2, new Date("2015/05/06"))
        .setParameter(toDate2, new Date("2015/05/06"))
        .setParameter(fromDate3, new Date("2015/05/04"))
        .setParameter(toDate3, new Date("2015/05/06"))
        .getResultList();
```

It produces the following SQL query.

```sql
SELECT
    cars0_.car_id AS car_id1_7_,
    cars0_.manufacturer AS manufact2_7_ 
FROM
    project.cars cars0_ 
WHERE
    NOT (EXISTS (SELECT
        1 
    FROM
        project.bookings bookings1_ 
    WHERE
        (bookings1_.from_date<=? 
        AND bookings1_.to_date>=? 
        OR bookings1_.from_date<=? 
        AND bookings1_.to_date>=? 
        OR bookings1_.from_date>=? 
        AND bookings1_.to_date<=?) 
        AND cars0_.car_id=bookings1_.fk_car_id))
```

Which returns the same result list.

---

**Additional:**

Here `subquery.select(criteriaBuilder.literal(1L));`, while using expressions like `criteriaBuilder.literal(1L)` in complex sub-query statements on EclipseLink, EclipseLink [gets confused](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23365839/1391249) and causes an exception. Therefore, it may need to be taken into account while writing complex sub-queries on EclipseLink. Just select an `id` in that case such as

```
subquery.select(subRoot.get(Bookings_.fkCarId).get(Cars_.carId));
```

as in the first case. Note : You will see an [odd behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24837320/1391249) in SQL query generation, if you run an expression as above on EclipseLink though the result list will be identical.

You may also use joins which turn out to be more efficient on back-end database systems in which case, you need to use `DISTINCT` to filter out possible duplicate rows, since you need a result list from the parent table. The result list may contain duplicate rows, if there exists more than one child row in the detailed table - `bookings` for a corresponding parent row  `cars`. <s>I am leaving it to you. :)</s> This is how it goes here.

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Cars> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Cars.class);
Metamodel metamodel = entityManager.getMetamodel();
Root<Cars> root = criteriaQuery.from(metamodel.entity(Cars.class));
criteriaQuery.select(root).distinct(true);

ListJoin<Cars, Bookings> join = root.join(Cars_.bookingsList, JoinType.LEFT);

ParameterExpression<Date> fromDate1 = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Date.class);
Predicate exp1 = criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(join.get(Bookings_.fromDate), fromDate1);
ParameterExpression<Date> toDate1 = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Date.class);
Predicate exp2 = criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(join.get(Bookings_.toDate), toDate1);
Predicate and1 = criteriaBuilder.and(exp1, exp2);

ParameterExpression<Date> fromDate2 = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Date.class);
Predicate exp3 = criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(join.get(Bookings_.fromDate), fromDate2);
ParameterExpression<Date> toDate2 = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Date.class);
Predicate exp4 = criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(join.get(Bookings_.toDate), toDate2);
Predicate and2 = criteriaBuilder.and(exp3, exp4);

ParameterExpression<Date> fromDate3 = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Date.class);
Predicate exp5 = criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(join.get(Bookings_.fromDate), fromDate3);
ParameterExpression<Date> toDate3 = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Date.class);
Predicate exp6 = criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(join.get(Bookings_.toDate), toDate3);
Predicate and3 = criteriaBuilder.and(exp5, exp6);

Predicate or = criteriaBuilder.not(criteriaBuilder.or(and1, and2, and3));
Predicate isNull = criteriaBuilder.or(criteriaBuilder.isNull(join.get(Bookings_.fkCarId)));
criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.or(or, isNull));

List<Cars> list = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery)
        .setParameter(fromDate1, new Date("2015/05/04"))
        .setParameter(toDate1, new Date("2015/05/04"))
        .setParameter(fromDate2, new Date("2015/05/06"))
        .setParameter(toDate2, new Date("2015/05/06"))
        .setParameter(fromDate3, new Date("2015/05/04"))
        .setParameter(toDate3, new Date("2015/05/06"))
        .getResultList();
```

It produces the following SQL query.

```sql
SELECT
    DISTINCT cars0_.car_id AS car_id1_7_,
    cars0_.manufacturer AS manufact2_7_ 
FROM
    project.cars cars0_ 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    project.bookings bookingsli1_ 
        ON cars0_.car_id=bookingsli1_.fk_car_id 
WHERE
    (
        bookingsli1_.from_date>? 
        OR bookingsli1_.to_date<?
    ) 
    AND (
        bookingsli1_.from_date>? 
        OR bookingsli1_.to_date<?
    ) 
    AND (
        bookingsli1_.from_date<? 
        OR bookingsli1_.to_date>?
    ) 
    OR bookingsli1_.fk_car_id IS NULL
```

As can be noticed the Hibernate provider inverses the conditional statements in the `WHERE` clause in response to `WHERE NOT(...)`. Other providers may also generate the exact `WHERE NOT(...)` but after all, this is the same as the one written in the question and yields the same result list as in the previous  cases.

<sub>Right joins are not specified. Hence, JPA providers do not have to implement them. Most of them do not support right joins.</sub>

---

Respective JPQL just for the sake of completeness :)

The `IN()` query :

```sql
SELECT c 
FROM   cars AS c 
WHERE  c.carid NOT IN (SELECT b.fkcarid.carid 
                       FROM   bookings AS b 
                       WHERE  b.fromdate <=? 
                              AND b.todate >=? 
                              OR b.fromdate <=? 
                                 AND b.todate >=? 
                              OR b.fromdate >=? 
                                 AND b.todate <=? )
```

The `EXISTS()` query :

```sql
SELECT c 
FROM   cars AS c 
WHERE  NOT ( EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                     FROM   bookings AS b 
                     WHERE  ( b.fromdate <=? 
                              AND b.todate >=? 
                              OR b.fromdate <=? 
                                 AND b.todate >=? 
                              OR b.fromdate >=? 
                                 AND b.todate <=? ) 
                            AND c.carid = b.fkcarid) )
```

The last one that uses the left join (with named parameters):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT c FROM Cars AS c 
LEFT JOIN c.bookingsList AS b 
WHERE NOT (b.fromDate <=:d1 AND b.toDate >=:d2
           OR b.fromDate <=:d3 AND b.toDate >=:d4
           OR b.fromDate >=:d5 AND b.toDate <=:d6)
           OR b.fkCarId IS NULL
```

All of the above JPQL statements can be run using the following method as you already know.

```
List<Cars> list=entityManager.createQuery("Put any of the above statements", Cars.class)
                .setParameter("d1", new Date("2015/05/04"))
                .setParameter("d2", new Date("2015/05/04"))
                .setParameter("d3", new Date("2015/05/06"))
                .setParameter("d4", new Date("2015/05/06"))
                .setParameter("d5", new Date("2015/05/04"))
                .setParameter("d6", new Date("2015/05/06"))
                .getResultList();
```

Replace named parameters with corresponding indexed/positional parameters as and when needed/required.

All of these JPQL statements also generate the identical SQL statements as those generated by the criteria API as above.

---

- I would always avoid `IN()` sub-queries in such situations and especially while
  using MySQL. I would use `IN()` sub-queries if and only if they are
  absolutely needed for situations such as when we need to determine a
  result set or delete a list of rows based on a list of static values such as

  ```sql
  SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);`
  DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id IN(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
  ```

  and alike.
- I would always prefer queries using the `EXISTS` operator in such situations, since the result list involves
  only a single table based on a condition in another table(s). Joins
  in this case will produce duplicate rows as mentioned earlier that need to be filtered out
  using `DISTINCT` as shown in one of the queries above.
- I would preferably use joins, when the result set to be retrieved is
  combined from multiple database tables - have to be used anyway as obvious.

Everything is dependent upon many things after all. Those are not milestones at all.

<sub>**Disclaimer :** I have a very little knowledge on RDBMS.</sub>

---

<sub>**Note :** I have used the parameterized/overloaded **deprecated** date constructor -  `Date(String s)` for indexed/positional parameters associated with the SQL query in all the cases for a pure testing purpose only to avoid the whole mess of `java.util.SimpleDateFormat` noise which you already know. You may also use other better APIs like Joda Time (Hibernate has support for it), `java.sql.*` (those are  sub-classes of `java.util.Date`), Java Time in Java 8 (mostly not supported as of now unless customized) as and when required/needed.</sub>

Hope that helps.

Comment: Wow, that's beyond doubt the best and most detailed answer I've ever got on the internet. Thanks so much! Helped me really a lot.

Comment: I was also interested in completing the answer :) Thank you. @StevenX

Comment: This one is a great answer. Solved a lot of queries

Answer (score 2):

It will run faster if you do this format:

```
SELECT c.*
    FROM cars c
    LEFT JOIN bookings b 
             ON b.fkCarId = c.id
            AND (b.fromDate ... )
    WHERE b.fkCarId IS NULL;
```

This form still won't be very efficient since it will have to scan all `cars`, then reach into `bookings` once per.

You do need an index on `fkCarId`.  "fk" smells like it is a `FOREIGN KEY`, which implies an index.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for confirmation.

If CriteriaBuilder can't build that, complain to them or get it out of your way.

Flipping it around *might* run faster:

```
SELECT c.*
    FROM bookings b 
    JOIN cars c
           ON b.fkCarId = c.id
    WHERE NOT (b.fromDate ... );
```

In this formulation, I am hoping to do a table scan on `bookings`, filtering out the reserved chars, an d only then reach into `cars` for the desired rows.  This might be especially faster if there are very few available cars.